# Spring Security with OpenIDAuthenticationFilter problem

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have some difficulties to make the OpenIDAuthenticationFilter working, I hope someone can help me.

My spring-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <security:http pattern="/myapp/auth/login" security="none"/>

    <security:http entry-point-ref="entryPoint">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/myapp/main/*" access="ROLE_USER"/>
        <security:logout/>
        <security:custom-filter position="OPENID_FILTER" ref="openIdAuthFilter"/>
    </security:http>

  <bean id="openIdAuthFilter" class="org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
      <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl"
          value="/myapp/auth/login?login_error=true"/>
      </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="consumer">
      <bean class="org.springframework.security.openid.OpenID4JavaConsumer">
        <constructor-arg index="0">
          <bean class="org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerManager"/>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="1">
          <list value-type="org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAttribute">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAttribute">
              <constructor-arg index="0" value="email"/>
              <constructor-arg index="1" value="http://schema.openid.net/contact/email"/>             
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAttribute">
              <constructor-arg index="0" value="firstName"/>
              <constructor-arg index="1" value="http://axschema.org/namePerson/first" />
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAttribute">
              <constructor-arg index="0" value="lastName"/>
              <constructor-arg index="1" value="http://axschema.org/namePerson/last" />
            </bean>
          </list>
        </constructor-arg>
      </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>


    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
      <security:authentication-provider ref="openIdAuthProvider"/>
    </security:authentication-manager>
  <bean id="openIdAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="authenticationUserDetailsService" ref="registeringUserService"/>
  </bean>

<!--
    A custom UserDetailsService which will allow any user to authenticate and "register" their IDs in an internal map
    for use if they return to the site. This is the most common usage pattern for sites which use OpenID.
 -->
    <bean id="registeringUserService" class="org.myapp.openid.service.CustomUserDetailsService" />

  <bean id="entryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/myapp/auth/login"/>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

The org.myapp.openid.service.CustomUserDetailsService.java

```
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService, AuthenticationUserDetailsService {
    private final Map registeredUsers = new HashMap();
    private static final List DEFAULT_AUTHORITIES = AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER");

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String id) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserDetails user = registeredUsers.get(id);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(id);
        }

        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Implementation of {@code AuthenticationUserDetailsService} which allows full access to the submitted
     * {@code Authentication} object. Used by the OpenIDAuthenticationProvider.
     */
    public UserDetails loadUserDetails(OpenIDAuthenticationToken token) {
        String id = token.getIdentityUrl();
        CustomUserDetails user = registeredUsers.get(id);

        if (user != null) {
            return user;
        }

        String email = null;
        String firstName = null;
        String lastName = null;
        String fullName = null;

        List attributes = token.getAttributes();

        for (OpenIDAttribute attribute : attributes) {
            if (attribute.getName().equals("email")) {
                email = attribute.getValues().get(0);
            }

            if (attribute.getName().equals("firstname")) {
                firstName = attribute.getValues().get(0);
            }

            if (attribute.getName().equals("lastname")) {
                lastName = attribute.getValues().get(0);
            }

            if (attribute.getName().equals("fullname")) {
                fullName = attribute.getValues().get(0);
            }
        }

        if (fullName == null) {
            StringBuilder fullNameBldr = new StringBuilder();

            if (firstName != null) {
                fullNameBldr.append(firstName);
            }

            if (lastName != null) {
                fullNameBldr.append(" ").append(lastName);
            }
            fullName = fullNameBldr.toString();
        }
        ....
    }
}
```

when i am debugging, method loadUserByUsername(), there is a Url returned, but the OpenIDAttributes are null (email,firstname and lastname).

I think I must configured the spring-security.xml wrong, please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just make attributes requierd:

```
`<beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAttribute">
                    <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="email" />
                    <beans:constructor-arg index="1" value="http://schema.openid.net/contact/email" />
                    <beans:property name="required" value="true"/>
</beans:bean>`
```